# Trying to use Sass variables inside Vue scoped css

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Working on a laravel spa and trying to use Sass variables inside an Vue scoped css but they are not loading. Am I missing something or isnt this anymore possible? When I use the variables inside the gobal scss file it will work.

```
root/
- resources/
  - js/
    - components/
  - sass/
    - _variables.scss
- vue.config
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.11",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.2.5",
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "jquery": "^3.6",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.18",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "node-sass": "^6.0.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
        "postcss": "^8.2.15",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
        "sass": "^1.32.11",
        "sass-loader": "^11.1.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^2.1.2",
        "vue": "^3.0.5",
        "vue-loader": "^16.1.2",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.7.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.3.2",
        "@vue/cli": "^4.5.13",
        "browser-sync": "^2.26.14",
        "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
        "npm-watch": "^0.9.0",
        "postcss-import": "^14.0.2",
        "vue-i18n": "^8.24.4",
        "vue-router": "^4.0.8",
        "vue-unicons": "^3.2.1",
        "vuex": "^4.0.0"
    }
}
```

**vue.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    css: {
      loaderOptions: {
        sass: {         
            prependData: `@import "./resources/sass/_variables.scss";`
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**component.vue**

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>    
   body{
      background: $body-color;
   }    
</style>
```

**Solution (for now)**

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>    
   @import "../../sass/componentBlabla.scss";    
</style>
```

Comment: Your `additionalData` is configured for sass but you are using scss ...fix thin in `vue.config.js` and it should work

Comment: What is the test for your `sass` rule in css loader options? Does it target `.sass` files or `.s(c|a)ss`? Because `.sass` doesn't support semicolons and `.scss` requires them I've had trouble before trying to configure prependData for both syntaxes from the same rule.

Answer (score 0):

In your file **webpack.mix.js** add this line

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.vue().sass('resources/sass/_variables.scss', 'public/css');
```

Observe closely in the function `sass()` i added the full path of the file **_variables.scss**.

Then run this command `npm run dev`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I already have this, but this is global, and this is not working for scoped css

Comment: Well then in that case import the _variables.css in your components inside the style tag

Comment: Yes thats a way to do it, but I don't want to add this in every component

Comment: I agree with you plus it's not an efficient method. I also noticed that you've used a recent version of sass loader and the approach you've used works for sass loader version 8. Try downgrading your sass loader to version 8 and run your code again.

Comment: downgrading will result into an compatibility issue

Comment: The sass loader is recent just loaded 13 days ago. Downgrade the sass loader version together with its dependencies so that you can avoid compatibility issues.